# Calculate video file md5(hash)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift3

I have to calculate of checksum of selected files (image,video)

in my code image calculation working great but video calculation not working at all.

I am using CryptoSwift

Here is my code what I did

```
import CryptoSwift

class MD5Calculator {

    static func imageChecksum(imageArray: [UIImage], onCalculated: @escaping ([String]) -> Void){

        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {

            var array: [String] = []                        
            for chosenImage in imageArray {
                if let jpegData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(chosenImage, 80) {
                    let checksum = jpegData.md5()
                    let chsum = checksum.toHexString()
                    array.append(chsum)
                }
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                onCalculated(array)
            }
        }
    }

    static func videoChecksum(videoURLs:[NSURL], onCalculated: @escaping ([String]) -> Void) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {

            var array: [String] = []

            for url in videoURLs {
                if let videoData = Data(contentsOf: url as URL, options: Data.ReadingOptions) {
                    let checksum = videoData.md5()
                    let chsum = checksum.toHexString()
                    array.append(chsum)

                }
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                onCalculated(array)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

in videoChecksum I can't get Data I have syntax error in line

```
 if let videoData = Data(contentsOf: url as URL, options: Data.ReadingOptions)
```

Error is:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'Data.ReadingOptions.Type' (aka 'NSData.ReadingOptions.Type') to expected argument type 'Data.ReadingOptions' (aka 'NSData.ReadingOptions')
```

And this is Data class constructor

```
public init(contentsOf url: URL, options: Data.ReadingOptions = default) throws
```

My question is

**1. how could I get Data of video file**

**2. If there is another way to get Data and calculate checksum please suggest me**

**3. If you know what syntax error it please tell me how to fix it.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you have a syntax error when calling

```
let videoData = Data(contentsOf: url as URL, options: Data.ReadingOptions)
```

because the `options` parameter is expecting one of `ReadingOptions` values and you are passing the type itself. A valid call looks like this:

```
let videoData = Data(contentsOf: url as URL, options: Data.ReadingOptions.uncached)
```

(See [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdata.readingoptions) for possible values.)

If you're unsure about what value to provide, you can omit passing the parameter as it is defaulted, i.e:

```
let videoData = Data(contentsOf: url as URL)
```

---

**Edit:**
Also note that the `Data(contentsOf:options:)` initialiser "`throws`" so ideally you should wrap the call in a do / try / catch statement like this:

```
for url in videoURLs {
    do {
        let videoData = try Data(contentsOf: url as URL)
        let checksum = videoData.md5()
        let chsum = checksum.toHexString()
        array.append(chsum)
    } catch {
        // TODO: Handle error
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Glad to hear :) Also see my edit about exception handling.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [asset defaultRepresentation];
Byte *buffer = (Byte*)malloc((NSUInteger)rep.size);
NSUInteger buffered = [rep getBytes:buffer fromOffset:0.0 length:(NSUInteger)rep.size error:nil];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:buffered freeWhenDone:YES];